# Requests taking longer time in Netty server under high load

Tags: java, netty

We have built a real time system using Netty framework for handling our HTTP requests. 20 % of the calls made to the service are long poll in nature, where we reply after 55 seconds in most of the cases.

As the load increases, response time gradually increases and Under high load conditions (20000 long poll connections and 10000 short poll connections established), the response time goes above 5 sec.

We confirmed that the requests are delayed at netty server level. All the other factors (Client, Nginx,  Server business logic) are verified to be a non-issue. We even tried running our tests with our business logic completely removed. Still the results were same.

Can somebody throw some light on how to tune Netty to handle such loads.

Shiva.

Comment: It seems like part of your question got cut off. Can you add the rest of the details in an edit?

Comment: Yes please add the missing parts of your post.

Comment: Sorry guys. Missed it while posting. Added the complete text now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have not yet put the handling of this 20% of requests behind an ExecutionHandler at your pipelines. If that's the case then your worker threads are stuck waiting and can not handle new requests. Although you could make sure that those requests that can be processed immediately are handled before that ExecutionHandler.

org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler

Comment: Sounds Interesting. I will give it a try.